# JAAS does not work on CentOS 6

Tags: java, tomcat6, jaas, centos6

I'm trying to implement JAAS security for my Java application. On the Windows 7 OS everything is working fine but when I'm trying to do the same things on the CentOS6 server, JAAS does not work: secured services are not available due to 404 (Not Found) error.

Here is my code:

2nd line of catalina.sh (after the #!/bin/sh line):

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.auth.login.config==$CATALINA_HOME/conf/jaas.config"
```

conf/jaas.config:

```
SomeLogin {
    package.SomeLoginModule required debug=true;
};
```

project/META-INF/context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm" 
  appName="SomeLogin"
  userClassNames="package.UserPrincipal"
  roleClassNames="package.RolePrincipal" />
</Context>
```

project/WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Registration</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/xml/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>manager</role-name>
        <role-name>channel</role-name>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-role>
    <role-name>manager</role-name>
    <role-name>channel</role-name>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.html</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

Also, I've tried to add the environment variables like JAVA_OPTS and CATALINA_OPTS with setted java.security.auth.login.config property but nothing helps.

I've started up the Tomcat with -security flag but it seems that it is not related to JAAS. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

When I try to get some of the /xml/* paths, it only returns a 404 error. If I change the web.xml so application would be unsecured, everything works fine.

I tried to reproduce this case on the Windows OS but nothing helps: login page always shows.

Can someone help me please to find out what am I missing?

My env: Tomcat 6.0.37, CXF, Java 6u45, CentOS6 (x64) - JAAS does not work/Windows 7 (x64) - JAAS works.

P.S. If you need the Principals and LoginModule code, please let me know.

UPD: I've found that error is related to the ServletController

*Can't find the the request for [address to the login.html page] Observer (ServletController.java:161)*

Thanks,
R.